# Material UI Vertical Divider within Grid not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to place a vertical `<divider>` within a grid as a  but it is not showing. When I remove it and do not put it within a `<Grid Item>` it shows but I believe is not the correct way. What is missing here:

```
<Grid container justifyContent="space-between" spacing={1}>
    <Grid item>
        <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
            <Grid item>
                Something
            </Grid>
            <Grid item >
                <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
            </Grid>   
            <Grid item>
                Something else
            </Grid>         
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just without the surrounding Grid item is fine:

```
<Grid container justifyContent="space-between" spacing={1}>
  <Grid item>
    <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
      <Grid item>Something</Grid>
      <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
      <Grid item>Something else</Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

See as well [Vertical with text example](https://mui.com/components/dividers/#vertical-with-text) in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I had read somewhere it was not best practice but it clearly is fine. How can I change the height of the divider in the example above? When I add `style={{height="50%"}}` it fails.